# Sass not compiling properly to application.css rails 7

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I have setup a new rails 7 project with Bootstrap 5.2 and Sass, however when it comes to adding in custom styling (with Sass) Rails appears to not be compiling the Sass styling into `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`. I have no errors to go off here and after spending far too long on the problem, decided to start fresh with the following setup instructions - [https://railsbytes.com/public/templates/V2Gsg9](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I had to remove the `@import "bootstrap"` code below as this throws a compilation error.

```
append_file 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss', <<-CODE
@import "bootstrap";
CODE
```

I'm unsure if this is relevant to the issue, however I was having issues with the bootstrap setup, where the JavaScript was not working, and followed the following setup from another stackoverflow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907799/bootstrap-5-javascript-functions-not-working-in-rails-7-app](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) which has fixed this issue.

In summary, the only problem I'm now facing is that the css is not compiling. I found a number of other resources related to the same issue, however the setup is slightly different and when I try to run the solutions provided it does not work. I have seen multiple posts suggesting to attempt to run `rails assets:precompile`, which I did, however it broke all the styling setup and couldn't revert it back for some reason (part of the reason whey I started on a new project).

In addition to the new setup, I also tried this suggestion by "stevec" in the following [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300845/custom-css-not-working-with-css-bundling-for-rails-7](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). This works, however it doesn't seem to be the Rails way of doing things. This suggests each stylesheet needs to be added to the `app/assets/config/manifest.js` and also to the `application.html.erb` file. To my understanding, each view should have its own style sheet which is then imported into `application.css`.

I feel I'm close to the solution but am finding it challenging at the moment to understand the documentation on the asset pipeline... Some recommendations suggest to install yarn/npm however I thought that's the benefit/job of `importmap` so have not gone down that path